# "Insufficient Permission for this file" when using Google Advanced Drive API to set contentRestiction.readOnly even if I am the owner

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to prevent accidental editing of a Google Form which is automatically generated using a series of Google Scripts and Google Sheet data. To do so, I have read some documentation and I have switched from the standard DriveApp object to the Advanced Drive API (v2 as in Script there isn't yet the v3 available) to access the contentRestrictions.readOnly metadata.

**Please notice that I am using a Shared Drive, not the standard MyDrive**

I have written a very simple function to set the parameter to true and set a reason:

```
/**
 * Locks a file given it's unique ID. This should prevent 
 * accidental editing of the file.
 * @param {String} File unique ID
 */
function setFileLock(fileId) {
  
  var resource = {
    contentRestrictions: [{readOnly: true, 
                           reason: 'This file is locked to prevent accidental editing'}]
  }
  
  Drive.Files.patch(resource, fileId, { supportsAllDrives: true });
}
```

I do have all the related scopes in the appscript.json:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Paris",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
      "userSymbol": "Drive",
      "serviceId": "drive",
      "version": "v2"
    }]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"],
  "executionApi": {
    "access": "DOMAIN"
  },
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

Even if I am the owner of a file, and when checking for the permissions using Drive.Files.get, I can see that I am the owner and I have 'organizer' (which is Content Manager) rights, I keep on getting the error "Insufficient permissions for this file" (403). Notice that from the same script I can use Drive.Files.touch which actually updates the file without problems.

Does anyone else have similar problems? It seems to be only related to the `contentRestrictions` properties, I can change `title` and `description` for example.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, I am kind of stuck.

Thanks!

Comment: DalmTo, I am not sure I understand your question. I am using Google Apps Script, and when you run the script is launching a pop-up asking to authorize the Script for all of the scopes that I have posted above. Every time I change the appscript.json file I am asked to re-authorize. I am not aware of specific authorization code... maybe it is the piece that I am missing?

Comment: Double check the user your logging in with is the user that owns the file  that error message means you dont have permission to do what your trying to do.  If its not scope related then it must be user access related.

Comment: Please provide your exact request to check for permissions that results in 403.

Comment: As already commented above to @DalmTo I do not have a specific authorization request, I am using the Google App Script advanced drive API (v2) which is a wrapper to the HTTP APIs. The fact that I do have the scope in the appscript.json makes the pop-up with authorization come up for the user. Even if I try to use the Try now (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/patch?apix=true#try-it) with the HTTP request it still fails with 403 even if I am the file owner, and I can change `title` and `description` with the same API call. Only `contentRestrictions` returns the error.

Comment: Have you tried `Drive.Files.update({'contentRestrictions': [{'readOnly': true}]})` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `contentRestrictions` cannot be applied to all file types

It works e.g. for Google Docs and Google Sheets (as you can verify yourself), but not e.g. for folders and unfortunately neither for Google Forms.

Comment: Darn! That's the problem, it works with Spreadsheet, but not with Forms. Is this a temporal situation or is it by design? Is there any place where this information can be found?

Comment: I believe it is by design. Theofficial information is limited - after all the feature is new. This is what I found: https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2020/10/lock-files-using-the-google-drive-api.html https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PoE922Ozgdn7wSOg7j4S8U84FK3y9aLxyt12bNcdQ-4/edit#heading=h.kzc876ui7hr3

Comment: Thanks Ziganotschka, same documentation I have read, and there is written: "You can now add and remove content restrictions via the Drive API. By using the new ContentRestriction API, any file type in Drive can be “locked,” preventing changes to the item’s content, title, and comments"... so I suppose **any file type** should include also Forms.

Comment: In this case it might a bug and you can report in on [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).

Answer (score 0):

The `readOnly` attribute in the payload should be a boolean, not string.

```
'readOnly': true
```

Comment: Thanks Amit Agarwal, I have tried to pass the whole block as javascript object as well but doesn't make any difference. I think the API wrapper is using JSON encoding to send an HTTP request anyway. The problem is permissions.

Comment: I wrote a script that uses the Drive API with `UrlFetchApp` to make files read-only. Can you check if that works? https://www.labnol.org/code/read-only-google-drive-file-201011

Comment: You already have the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` scope that is required for the API.

Comment: Thanks @Amit, I have tried to execute the API from the documentation (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/patch?apix=true#try-it) which uses the same approach you use in your script by posting a direct HTTP request. It still returns 403, Not enough permissions, even if I can change the title and description of the file. And notice that I am using a Shared Drive, not My Drive, this is why the request need to have the `{ supportAllDrives: true }`